# Select's Where Clause - Non Ascii Characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm having a problem with non-ASCII characters in a where clause

Say for example a record in my table has :

**column_a** Bom D� Street

And I want to see if this will find the record:

```
SELECT * FROM [tbl_test] where column_a = 'Bom D� Street'
```

This always returns no records.

Is there something you have to do to handle non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:  SELECT * FROM [tbl_test] where column_a = N'Bom D� Street'

This should treat the string as unicode and support the full extended character set.

Comment: Should this be handled in a stored procedure if you're using parameters of type NVARCHAR?

Comment: @Adam - It certainly could be, but I wouldn't say it has to be.

Comment: after 2 hours of searching i found this.. know we're not supposed to but THANK YOU!!